# Can't acces to admin panel wordpress

Tags: wordpress, admin, panel

Hi I have tried to enter to my admin panel, but I have these errors:

> Warning:
>   require(/home/fundacioilles/public_html/wp-admin/menu-header.php)
>   [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in /home/fundacioilles/public_html/wp-admin/admin-header.php on line
>   194
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   '/home/fundacioilles/public_html/wp-admin/menu-header.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/fundacioilles/public_html/wp-admin/admin-header.php on line 194

I have renamed the plugin folder, to see if it was from the plugins, but it seems that's not the problem.
I have deleted all themes that I'm not using, and renamed my theme, but it didn't work either.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Looks to me like your wp-admin directory is missing some files. Reinstall.

Comment: I'd guess that one of the "themes I'm not using" was actually the admin theme. You should be able to FTP just that directory up from the WordPress download package.